# SAS Column adding a backslash

Tags: string, sas, concatenation

I was wondering how I can concatenate a two column values in SAS.

For Example Column A has a value 2006 and Column B has a value of 2007.

How do I get Column C to be 2006/2007 ? I am unable to get concatenate using the forward slash.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code that was unable to concatenate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CATX Function

```
data _null_;
   c = catx('/', '2006', '2007');
   put c=;
run;
```

Comment: Hi @draycut. I have given this a tick and have accepted the answer.